# How to set a cookie for twitter web app login?

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, twitter

This code is to set a cookie for twitter authentication for a web app.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['test'])){
require_once ('codebird.php');
Codebird::setConsumerKey('<key>', '<key>'); 
$cb = Codebird::getInstance();
session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])) {
    // gets a request token
    $reply = $cb->oauth_requestToken(array(
        'oauth_callback' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    ));

    // stores it
    $cb->setToken($reply->oauth_token, $reply->oauth_token_secret);
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $reply->oauth_token;
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $reply->oauth_token_secret;

    // gets the authorize screen URL
    $auth_url = $cb->oauth_authorize();
    header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
    die();

} else {
    // gets the access token
    $cb->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    $reply = $cb->oauth_accessToken(array(
        'oauth_verifier' => $_GET['oauth_verifier']
    ));

    // store the authenticated token, which may be different from the request token (!)
    $token = $reply->oauth_token;
    $secret = $reply->oauth_token_secret;
    $screen_name1 = $reply->screen_name;

   // now store these three variables in the db
setcookie("test", $screen_name1, time()+3600*30);

$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'twitter;
$username = 'username';
$password = '****';
$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if(!$conn){
die("Unable to Connect localhost!".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database!".mysql_error());
$query = 'INSERT INTO cookie(cookie_name,screen_name,time) VALUES ("test","'.$screen_name1.'",'.strval(time()).')';
if(!mysql_query($query,$conn))
{
    die('Error: '.mysql_error());   
}

     header("Location: http://www.example.com/user.php?screen_name=".$screen_name1."");
die();
}
}
```

The problem is after the die();
When the user log into the web app and exits it. After some time if he opens the web page again it should direct him to his page on the web app without having him to login again. The cookie solves that problem. But because of the die() function it can't fetch the $screen_name1 from the above part of the code to the below one resulting in the display of a blank page when the user logs in again.

```
else{ 


session_start();
$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'twitter';
$username = 'username';
$password = '****';

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if(!$conn){
die("Unable to Connect localhost!".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database!".mysql_error());

$value = mysql_query("SELECT screen_name FROM cookie WHERE screen_name='".$screen_name1."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($value);

  $screen_name = $row['screen_name'];
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $screen_name?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/biostories.ico" />
</head>
                  <body class="wrapper">

                  <div class="header">
                        <img src="images/header.jpg" usemap = #example border=0> 
                        <map name=example>
                        <area shape=Rect Coords= 1032,25,1177,90 Href="http://hansacequity.com/"> 
                        </map>
                  </div>

                  <div class="intro">
                    <p>@<?php echo($screen_name)?>  </p>

                    </div>

<?php
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database!".mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM bio_archives WHERE screen_name="'.$screen_name.'" ORDER BY timestamp DESC');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
    ?>
    <div class="biostories">
    <div class="image">
                   <img src ="images/line.png";  />
                  </div>
    <div class="color">
    <?php echo $row['bio'];?>
    </div>

    <div class="time">
    <?php echo ("Last updated on "."&nbsp;&nbsp;".date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$row['timestamp']));?>
    </div>
                  </div>
                  </body>
                  </html>

<?php
}           
?>
                    <div class="image1">
                    <img src ="images/line.png";  />
                    </div>
                   <?php
}           
?>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the cookie which is getting stored in the browser and paste it at the start of the else loop and store it in the variable screen_name1

$screen_name1= $_COOKIE["COOKIE NAME"];

Comment: Yeah that worked. Just this one important line of code was missed by me.